# Cargar imagen en servidor y obtener su ruta

Tags: php, html, formularios

Explico la idea y seguidamente la situación en la que me encuentro.

> La idea es cargar la imagen obtenida a través del formulario html llamando al php en el servidor, y después (o durante depende como se mire) obtener la ruta de la imagen cargada previamente en el servidor para poder realizar un consulta SQL de tipo INSERT con la ruta de la imagen, y el título y el contenido que son strings obtenidos del formulario, todo esto a través de una función.
>
> El problema está en que no logro colgar la imagen en el servidor ni capturar su ruta, además, no se muestra ningún tipo de mensaje con echo.

HTML

```
<form name="menus_create" action="events_create.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="menu_title">Título</label>
    <input name="menu_title" type="text" /></strong><br />
    <label for="menu_content">Contenido</label>
    <textarea name="menu_content"></textarea>​<br />
    <label for="menu_image">Imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="menu_image"> <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="CREAR">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

require_once('database/queries.php');
define("WEB_URL", "http://subdominio.dominio.es/carpeta1/carpeta2/");
define("INSERT_NULL", "No se ha podido continuar la inserción de datos     debido a la falta de algunos.");
define("INSERT_ERROR", "Ha ocurrido un error al intentar insertar nuevos datos en la base de datos.");


function getPathImage($image) {
    if ($_FILES[$image]['error'] > 0) { echo("No ha sido posible cargar la imagen."); }
    else {
        if (in_array($_FILES[$image]['type'], array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png")) && $_FILES[$image]['size'] <= 500 * 1024) {
        $path = "images/".$_FILES[$image]['name'];
        echo $path . ''; 
            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                $result = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'], $path);
                if (!$result) { return null; }
                else { return $path; }
            }
        } else {
            echo("No ha sido posible cargar la imagen.");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// AÑADIR MENÚ

if (isset($_POST['menu_create']) != null) {

    $menu_title     = $_POST['menu_title'];
    $menu_content   = $_POST['menu_content'];

    if ($menu_title != null && $menu_content != null) {
        try { Query::addMenu(WEB_URL . getPathImage('menu_image'), $menu_title, $menu_content); }
        catch (PDOException $e) { print_r($e); echo(INSERT_ERROR); }
    } else {
        echo(INSERT_NULL);
    }
}
//header('location: create.php');
?>
```

PD: Query es la clase que utilizo PDO para las consultas.

Comment: Si lo has solucionado, ponlo como respuesta y despues marcala como respuesta correcta. No coloques la respuesta en la pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error estaba en el html, intentaba capturar `menu_create` cuando estaba el `name` a `submit`.

Solucionado.